Nokia Beacon2 wireless to wireless connection
I am trying to extend my Root, BEACON2 MESH wireless to a specific corner of my apartment with an OLD Beacon1 extendor using wireless to wireless (Bridge mode). Do anyone have any experience to share to setup. I see on the Nokia APP, under advanced --Network-mode-Bridge - but not know impact if I setup wrongly.  If not using beacon1 can you tell me the steps for my Singtel MESH router (spare) setup.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
